# How can I redact personal-identification info (PII) in a URL when using gtag.js?

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I'm using the Google global site tag (gtag.js) to manage my tags, and I use it for Google Analytics.

Sometimes there is an email address in URLs on my site, and I need to remove that from the code.

I know there are [clever ways to get this done when using Google Tag Manager](https://brianclifton.com/blog/2017/09/07/remove-pii-from-google-analytics/). But I'm not using GTM, I'm using gtag.js. ([This simple page explains the difference](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7582054?hl=en).)

How can I check the current page's URL for email addresses and fix that, before the URL is tracked by gtag.js?

(I know how to do the regex etc... this is more asking where in the flow can I grab the URL and 'rewrite' it as needed before the Analytics pageview event posts?)

I looked through the [gtag.js API reference](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs) without much luck. Also looked at the [docs for how Analytics implements gtag.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs), still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed Google's documentation can be hard to explore sometime since they describe stuff only once for better maintenance and consistency, but at the end you could be missing a working summary ...

I would suggest to use this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/pages

```
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {
  'page_path': '/pagepath?email=redacted@example.com'
});
```